24.04 LTS - Service does not start automatically
I've recently installed 24.04 LTS server on a new machine, installed docker and docker-compose. I have services configured and working for both, but for docker-compose, it won't start up automatically.  I have enabled the service.  I can start the service from the command line, and my docker containers all start normally, as if I did the docker-compose up -d.  But, after a fresh boot... the docker service runs, but docker-compose-app.service does not.  If I try to start it, the error indicates 'Failed to start docker-compose-app.service: Unit docker-compose-app.service not found.'  But, if I systemctl list-unit-files, it reports a "state" and a "preset" of enabled.  If queried, it reports enabled and inactive.  If an attempt to start it is issued before the command to enable it is issued (even though it reports as enabled), the start fails.  Once you enable it (again), then it can be started.
user@server:/mnt$ sudo systemctl is-enabled docker-compose-app.service
enabled
user@server:/mnt$ sudo systemctl is-active docker-compose-app.service
inactive
user@server:/mnt$ sudo systemctl start docker-compose-app.service
Failed to start docker-compose-app.service: Unit docker-compose-app.service not found.
user@server:/mnt$ sudo systemctl enable docker-compose-app.service
user@server:/mnt$ sudo systemctl start docker-compose-app.service
user@server:/mnt$ sudo systemctl is-active docker-compose-app.service
active

What am I missing here?
